# Javascript-ORM-Wrapper for sqlite

Tags: javascript, sqlite, activerecord, orm, cordova

I am looking for ORM-Wrapper-implementations around Sqlite in Javascript like these once bundled with Ruby on rails for simple CRUD-Operations.

We build an App with phonegap and would like to work with Datamapping and/or ActiveRecord-Patterns instead of plain sql-queries.

Has anyone some good hints for us?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try with [persistance.js](http://persistencejs.org/)

There you can create you're javascript object like

```
var Foo = persistance.define('Foo', {
  bar: "TEXT"
}
var foo = new Foo({bar: "Bar"});
persistence.add(foo);
persistence.flush();
```

Then you can fetch information with something like Foo.all().filter().order().limit() It has support for migrations, transactions, synchronization with remote server, integration with jquery, etc.. You can check more in the documentation...